# Grails/Tomcat/MySQL stale connection error, even when using JNDI?

Tags: tomcat, grails, jdbc, jndi

I have a couple of Grails 1.3.3 application running on Tomcat 6.0.18.  I'm aware of the database connection staleness issue when using the default Grails datasource (connection gets killed after a period of inactivity), so I switched to JNDI provided by Tomcat.

The first app I deployed has never had any stale database connection problems.  Now I deployed a second app to the same server with the same JNDI datasource configuration, and while the first continues to work fine, the second app gets the connection timeout error after about 8 or so hours of inactivity.  (After the error the connection gets refreshed and it works just fine again)

The datasources are defined in Tomcat's context.xml as follows:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/firstDs" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="user1" password="password1" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/firstApp" />

<Resource name="jdbc/secondDs" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
    username="user2" password="password2" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secondApp" />
```

Both of the apps use the JNDI datasource in the Datasource.groovy file as follows (everything is exactly the same, except for the jndiName):

```
dataSource {
    pooled = false
}
...
environments {
    ...
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/firstApp"
        }
    }
}
```

The **ONLY** difference I'm aware of between these 2 situations is that working app uses MyISAM tables, while the non-working app uses InnoDB tables.  Has anyone experienced an issue with InnoDB and Tomcat connection pooling?  I may try switching to MyISAM if I can't find anything else to try.

Comment: The exception stacktrace would be helpful. - I'd also log at the `warn` level, including `org.hibernate`, `org.springframework`, and `com.mysql`. If any, indicators ought to be at the end of the log file when the exception occurs.

Comment: This worked for me (not jndi, so I'm providing a comment instead of and answer): http://www.sylvioazevedo.com.br/?p=56

Comment: Don't switch to MyISAM - there's no way that has any effect.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think so, but that's really the only difference between these apps and configs.  I just can't think of why one would have this problem and the other wouldn't.  Brad, thanks for the link, I think I'm going to apply that for now and if it works, that may be the permanent fix on Tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySQL and Grails it's best practice to have a validation query on the db pool. You might append to your  definitions:

```
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
```

See also http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources

Comment: validationQuery="SELECT 1" in the tomcat config or the grails config?

Comment: @chrislovecnm: nope, amend it to the resource definition in the tomcat config file